# Remix shows "creation of contract pending"

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

After deploying my contract, remix keeps showing " creation of contract pending ", not only this I am also getting a "Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: call revert exception " with my code. I am assuming the reason might be that the contract is yet not created. On checking metamask though, the status of the transaction shows as confirmed.
Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: Can you share your entire smart contract code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your wallet address on etherscan? The transaction details will certainly tell if the contract is created or not.